# Framework7 switch view in views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, view, html-framework-7

Seniors.

I have a question about Framework7.

The question is how do I switch view in views.

For example, I have...

#view1 main-view

#view2

#view3

#view4

so I use myApp.addView(view1),

myApp.addView(view2),

myApp.addView(view3),

myApp.addView(view4)

There had an example "Tab Bar Application".

I found that it use tab's < a > tag and href = '#view2', '#view3', '#view4',

then it can easily change view.

In short, how can I change view using code not just href link ?

Thanks, guys.

Comment: Same problem here. Not yet resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer; it's documented on Framework7's "Tabs" page under "Show Tab using javascript": http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/tabs.html#show-tab-using-javascript

Using the Tab demo here:
http://www.idangero.us/framework7/examples/tab-bar/

You can type this in the javascript console and it will swap to the "Photos" tab:
`myApp.showTab('#view-4')`

Answer (score 1):

For framework7 v2 :

if your view is

```
<div id="view-settings" class="view tab">
<!-- Settings page will be loaded here dynamically from /settings/ route -->
</div>
```

Then to show  tab on framework7 v2 programmatically use

> app.tab.show("#view-settings")

Answer (score -2):

You can use plain javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    location.href = "#view2";
}
```

for example...

Comment: Am I missing something obvious. That's not working for me on the tab-bar example: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/examples/tab-bar/.

If I drop `location.href='#view-4'` into the javascript console it doesn't change to the "Photos" tab but if I click on the "Photos" icon it, of course, does. 

What am I missing?